# SwiftUI - Hide the navigation bar on scroll

Tags: swiftui, ios13

I'm wanting to hide the toolbar as I scroll down a page and return it as I scroll up. I have seen this done in UIKit but wanting to know if someone has done this in SwiftUI?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've been playing around with this inside SwiftUI.
https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar

Comment: @user1631763, what was the results of your play? can you please let me know how you used that in a SwiftUI project?